# Accessing array of parameters inside the params[] value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have the following Parameters:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", 
  "authenticity_token"=>"06Us9R1wCPCJsD06TN7KIV/2ZeH4dJlZVqc12gpKBbo=",
  "run"=>{"box_id"=>"1"}, "tapes"=>{"1"=>{"tape_id"=>"1"},
  "2"=>{"tape_id"=>"2"}, "3"=>{"tape_id"=>"3"}}, "commit"=>"Create Run"}}
```

I want to create a new "Run" with the box id of 1 and then associate the tapes 1 2 and 3 to this run with the box id of 1

I am not sure what code needs to go into the controller, i did try:

```
def create
  @run = Run.new(params[:run])
  @tape_ids = @run.build_tape(params[:run][:tapes])

  @run.save
```

When i submit the form below, it creates a new Run with the correct box but associates no tapes with it.

```
<%= form_for(@run) do |f| %>
  <% if @run.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@run.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this tape
        from being saved:
      </h2>

      <ul>
        <% @run.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :box_id %>
    <br/>
    <%= f.text_field :box_id %>
  </div>

  <% (1..3).each do |index| %>
    <%= fields_for :tapes do |ff| %>

      <div class="field">
        <%= ff.label :tape_id , :index => index%>
        <%= ff.text_field :tape_id, :index => index %>
      </div>

    <% end %>
  <% end %>


  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Do you use `accepts_nested_attributes_for :tapes` in your Run model? Why dont you use nested form for tape_ids?

Comment: @hcK i could do, the run model is the join model for Tape and Box. I already have a list of tapes and boxes, I need to create a form where you can associate 24 existing tapes to one box, so I understood nested forms to be for creating new objects.

Comment: What is build_tape supposed to do?  What is it expecting as a parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not doing `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, then maybe this would work.  I don't know what `build_tape` is supposed to do, but the following will get you an array of tape_ids to work with:

```
@tape_ids = params[:run][:tapes].map { |k, v| v["tape_id"].to_i }
```

To complete the association, you could do something like

```
params[:run][:tapes].each do |k, v|
  t = Tape.find(v["tape_id"].to_i)
  t.run = @run
  t.save
end
```

Comment: Hello, a little late but this helped me when I was working on this some time ago, thanks.

Comment: Better late than never. :)  Glad it helped!