# ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments when creating multiple records

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an array called `actors` which contains objects, each object has data about an actor such as his name etc.

I'm trying to save the data in my SQLite db through Rails but I'm running into some problems.

I have tried several create functions in my actor controller,

```
def create
  actors = Actor.create(params[:actors])
  redirect_to :root
end
```

This creates a new record, although the content is emtpy,

```
{"id":8,"name":null,"character":null,"movie_id":null}
```

I thought maybe I need to add the parameters in the create function like so,

```
def create
  actors = Actor.create(params[:actors], movie_id: params[:movie_id], name: params[:name], character: params[:character])
  redirect_to :root
end
```

But this returns the error,

> ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (2 for 0..1))

*** update ***

This is the rails log from a post request,

```
Started POST "/actors.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-01-12 17:08:05 +0100
Processing by ActorsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"_json"=>[{"name"=>"Michael B. Jordan", "character"=>"Adonis Creed", "movie_id"=>312221}, {"name"=>"Sylvester Stallone", "character"=>"Rocky Balboa", "movie_id"=>312221}, {"name"=>"Graham McTavish", "character"=>"Tommy Holiday", "movie_id"=>312221}, {"name"=>"Tessa Thompson", "character"=>"Bianca", "movie_id"=>312221}, {"name"=>"Phylicia Rashād", "character"=>"Mary Anne Creed", "movie_id"=>312221}, {"name"=>"Hans Marrero", "character"=>"Flores", "movie_id"=>312221}, {"name"=>"Will Blagrove", "character"=>"James", "movie_id"=>312221}, {"name"=>"Tony Bellew", "character"=>"'Pretty' Ricky Conlan", "movie_id"=>312221}, {"name"=>"Ritchie Coster", "character"=>"Pete Sporino", "movie_id"=>312221}, {"name"=>"Jacob 'Stitch' Duran", "character"=>"Stitch", "movie_id"=>312221}, {"name"=>"Malik Bazille", "character"=>"Amir", "movie_id"=>312221}, {"name"=>"Wood Harris", "character"=>"Tony 'Little Duke' Burton", "movie_id"=>312221}, {"name"=>"Gabe Rosado", "character"=>"Leo 'The Lion' Sporino", "movie_id"=>312221}], "actor"=>{}}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 6ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
```

Comment: Essentially you can't do what you're trying, rails doesn't provide that functionality.  What is in the params?  You can either loop creating records or use `accepts_nested_attributes`.

Comment: I suggest you to take a look at http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/ClassMethods/create
can you show us the params?

Comment: @j-dexx how would you loop through through and create?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to iterate over every actor in the params[:actors] hash and assign the values of each param within that to your `Actor` model.

```
def create
  actors = params[:actors].each do |key, value|
      Actor.create({
        movie_id: value[:movie_id], 
        name: value[:name],
        character: value[:character]
      })
  end
  redirect_to :root
end
```

Disclaimer: I doubt this code is 100% right, I'm not sure if I did the syntax correctly for getting the values of the params (it would help to see what the params are), but this should put you in the right direction. Also try looking at these posts:

[Accessing array of parameters inside the params[] value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7783755/accessing-array-of-parameters-inside-the-params-value)

[Build array of objects from params hash after Transaction block fails, Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30036110/build-array-of-objects-from-params-hash-after-transaction-block-fails-rails)

EDIT: Try this...

```
def create
  actors = params[:json].each do |actor|
      Actor.create({
        movie_id: actor["movie_id"], 
        name: actor["name"],
        character: actor["character"]
      })
  end
  redirect_to :root
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I've tried the code but it returns a `NoMethodError (undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass):` So it looks like something is wrong with the `params[:actors]` right? I've added the rails console log output from a post request, maybe you can see what's going wrong from there.

Comment: That's right, the NilClass means that `params[:actors]` doesn't exist. Now that you pasted your parameters you can see why, right? Looks like you should replace that part of the code with `params[:_json]`

Comment: Thanks Haymaker, I'm mostly a front-end developer who's trying to learn some back-end stuff. Debugging rails is very hard for me, I can't see the logic quite yet often. I've changed it to `params[:_json]`. Now the log returns a `NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):` so it looks like rails sees the array as empty?

Comment: No problem, everyone has to go through the learning curve. What line does it say this error occurs on?

Comment: Edited my answer. I noticed that the keys in the array are in quotes. Hope this one works.

Comment: Pfiew. Combining a bit of your code and a bit of Atri's code I finally got it working that it would create a record for each actor but it was empty. Found it quite hard to figure out how to get the correct values in there. Glad you editted your sollution. So in the code `actor["movie_id"`, actor is the item that is being iterated and and then it grabs the "movie_id". Looks like it's working!

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass in a hash to the `create` method.

Do the following:

- Iterate over each object in `params[:actors]`

  ```
  params[:actors].each do |actor|
  ```
- Create the following hash with the values `name`, `character` and `movie_id` by extracting it from the object.

  ```
  hsh = {
    :name => actor.name,   #Assuming your actor object has this property
    :character => actor.character,  #Similarly actor.character
    :movie_id => actor.movie_id     #actor.movie_id
  }
  ```
- Now you can pass this to your `create` like:

  ```
  Actor.create(hsh)
  ```

**EDIT:**
After seeing your error log, it seems like you need to iterate through the `params[:_json]` array.

So you can simply do this:

```
params[:_json].each do |actor|
  Actor.create(actor)
end
```

This should work since each json document in `params[:_json]` is an actor hash.

Comment: Could you show how to iterate through the actors array?

Comment: This seems to be almost working. But it's returning `NoMethodError (undefined method name for #<ActionController::Parameters:0x007f40459bc170>):` so it looks like rails is having problems finding the correct values to insert.

Comment: Atri thank you for your help. As in my previous comment I had some troubles getting the correct data, it looks like it had to be `name: actor["name"],` thank you for sticking it out with me.